# Z3 pattern matching syntax

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, z3, smt

I'm trying to use pattern matching in z3 to work with algebraic datatypes. I'm exactly following the syntax given in the [SMTLib standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf) on page 27, but z3 is giving me a syntax error. For example in the following program:

```
(declare-datatype Dyn ((a) (b)))
(define-fun foo ((x Dyn)) Int (
  match x (
    (a 1)
    (b 2)
  )
))
(assert (= (foo a) (1)))
(check-sat)
```

it gives me the error "line 4 column 7: variable symbol expected". As far as I can tell I'm following the specified syntax exactly. How do I fix this?

Comment: As of Feb 3rd 2018, building z3 from github sources, this program is accepted just fine. Looks like they fixed the bug!

Comment: Great! I opened an issue about this on their github and they closed it, so it's good that it is indeed fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong! Looks like this is a z3 bug that you should report at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/

There's one little problem with your `assert` statement right before `(check-sat)`. It should read:

```
(assert (= (foo a) 1))
```

i.e., without any parenthesis around `1`. But your use of the `match` command is syntactically correct and should be reported as a z3 bug.